# Why are constants from extended module not available in class methods declared with self.?

Tags: ruby

I thought there were no differences between methods declared within a `class << self` block and those declared with a `self.` prefix, but there are:

```
module A
  VAR = 'some_constant'
end

class B
  extend A

  class << self
    def m1
      puts VAR
    end
  end

  def self.m2
    puts VAR
  end
end

B.m1 # => OK
B.m2 # => uninitialized constant B::VAR
```

Why are constants of `A` available in `m1` but not in `m2`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Ruby, constant lookup is not the same as method lookup. For method lookup, calling `foo` is always the same as calling `self.foo` (assuming it isn't private). Calling a constant `FOO` is very different from `self::FOO` or `singleton_class::FOO`.

Using an unqualified constant (e.g. `FOO`) will do a lookup in the currently opened modules. A module is opened with `module Mod`, `class Klass`, `class << obj`, or `module_eval` and variants. When defining `m1`, these are `B`, and then `B.singleton_class`. When defining `m2`, only `B` is opened.

```
module Foo
  X = 42
  class Bar
    def self.hello
      X
    end
  end
end
```

In this code, `Foo::Bar.hello` will return 42, even though `X` is not a constant of `Bar`, its singleton class or ancestor. Also, if you later add a constant `X` to `Bar`, then that value will be returned. Finally, the following definition is not equivalent:

```
module Foo
  X = 42
end

class Foo::Bar
  def self.hello
    X
  end
end

Foo::Bar.hello # => uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::X
```

Indeed, when `hello` is defined, only the class `Foo::Bar` is opened, while in the previous example, both `Foo` and `Foo::Bar` where opened.

A last example, to show the difference an explicit scope can have with inheritance:

```
class Base
  X = 42
  def self.foo
    X
  end
  def self.bar
    self::X
  end
end

class Parent < Base
  X = :other
end

Parent.foo # => 42
Parent.bar # => :other
```

In your case, **you probably want to `include` your module, instead of `extending` it**, no?

Otherwise, you could use `singleton_class::VAR`, your code will work as you expect it.

```
module A
  VAR = 'some_constant'
end

class B
  extend A

  class << self
    def m1
      puts singleton_class::VAR # not necessary here, as singleton_class is opened
    end
  end

  def self.m2
    puts singleton_class::VAR # necessary here!
  end
end

B.m1 # => OK
B.m2 # => OK
```

Comment: what is `f1` and `f2`? can you just add some lines there? What is `"currently opened modules"`?