# Mixins and class constants

Tags: ruby, mixins

I have 1 class and 1 module:

appointment.rb

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Appointments::Events

  ALERT = "hello!"

end
```

events.rb

```
module Appointments
  module Events
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def say_alert
      puts self.class::ALERT
    end
  end
end
```

calling **#say_alert** gives me:

```
uninitialized constant Module::ALERT
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420236/why-are-constants-from-extended-module-not-available-in-class-methods-declared-w

Comment: don't know ruby but it seems likely that it cannot find what ALERT is, likely a scope issue

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no answer, but the code is too long for a comment:

**In which sequence do you load your files?** And how do you call #say_alert?

This code works fine:

```
module Appointments
  module Events
    def say_alert
      puts self.class::ALERT
    end
  end
end

class Appointment 
  include Appointments::Events

  ALERT = "hello!"

end

Appointment.new.say_alert
```

---

After your comment: 
It works also with `ActiveSupport::Concern`:

```
require 'active_support'
module Appointments
  module Events
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    def say_alert
      puts self.class::ALERT
    end
  end
end

class Appointment 
  include Appointments::Events

  ALERT = "hello!"

end

Appointment.new.say_alert
```

I use ruby 2.1.5

Comment: The mixing Appointments::Events is used to delegate some functionality because the Appointment model is too big, so I need to call Appointment.last.say_alert and it should return => "hello!". I dont see any difference in your code, did it really worked for you?

Comment: it seems you removed the extend ActiveSupport::Concern

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple,

The problem was that I included the module in my class BEFORE the constants definitions. I also refactored my code a bit so it uses concerns properly as @rbates suggest at http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects

Now my code works:

app/models/appointment.rb

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  ALERTS = "hello!"

  include Events
end
```

app/models/concerns/appointment/events.rb

```
class Appointment
  module Events
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def say_alert
     puts ALERT
    end
  end
end
```

$ rails console

```
Appointment.last.say_alert
=> "hello!"
```